# How do I replace <img> with a custom image component in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a blog. I get the blog content html from an API. In my project I have an image component which handles the loading of the image a bit better then the default html img tag, that's why I want to replace it.

**I tried this:**

```
function replaceImages(html) {
  let tmp = document.createElement('div');
  tmp.innerHTML = html;

  let images = tmp.querySelectorAll('img');

  images.forEach((image, index) => {
    image.parentNode.replaceChild(<Image src={image.src} alt={image.alt}></Image>, image)
  })

  return tmp.innerHTML
}
```

**But I get this error:**

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is
>   not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Try `[images].forEach...` the reason is `querySelectorAll` returns a node list which needs to be converted into an array which can then be used with `.forEach()`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I can loop through images without converting the node list. So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney it's just basic html that contains: <p><h3><img> etc. I think I'm quite to accomplish what I want. I think that I just have to figure out how I can convert a component (<Image>) to a Node

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass your React element instance directly into the DOM.  That's why you're getting an error. `<Image>` isn't of type `Node` (as in native DOM `Node`).

You'll ned to use *some* form of React rendering to get an actualy DOM `Node`:

```
  images.forEach(image => {
    const host = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<Image src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />, host);
    image.parentNode.replaceChild(host.children[0], image)
  })
```